# How to place elements inside div in ReactJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am a complete beginner. I am making a simple game in React.

For this I am making a game board like this

[image]

As you can see, I have two div's stacked on top of each other in the left side. I would like to have two div's stacked on top of each other on the right side as well. How do I go about that?

**My code:**

**Board.js**

```
class Board extends Component {



    render() {
        return (
            <div className="board">
                <Square placement={'topLeft'}/>
                <Square placement={'bottomLeft'}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Board;
```

**Board.css**

```
.board{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: darkgray;
}

@media(max-width: 650px) {
    .board {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 90px auto 0;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

**Square.js**

```
const Square = (props) => {

    let className;

    switch (props.placement) {
        case 'topLeft':
            className='square topLeft';
            break;
        case 'bottomLeft':
            className = 'square bottomLeft';
    }


    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <p style={{fontSize:'100px'}}></p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Square;
```

**Square.css**

```
.square {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.topLeft{
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.bottomLeft{
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a two column grid and give inner borders to both the top left and bottom right squares.

Your code should look like this:

Board.js

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="board">
        <Square placement={'topLeft'}/>
        <Square placement={'topRight'}/>
        <Square placement={'bottomLeft'}/>  //added 2 more squares
        <Square placement={'bottomRight'}/>    
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Board.css

```
.board{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; //two equal size columns layout
}

@media(max-width: 650px) {
  .board {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 90px auto 0; //You don't need to add the border again inside the media query
  }
}
```

Squares.js

```
const Square = (props) => {
  let className;
  switch (props.placement) {
    case 'topLeft':
      className='square topLeft';
      break;
    case 'topRight':
      className='square'
      break;
    case 'bottomLeft':
      className='square';
      break;
    case 'bottomRight':
      className = 'square bottomRight';
  }
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <p style={{fontSize:'100px'}}></p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Squares.css

```
.square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topLeft{
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.bottomRight{
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the job.